# How can I show a react component in all routes except one?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want my ProjectButton component to render in all routes except for /projects. Is there a way a can handle this with react router?

```
<Router>
    <React.Fragment>
      <Route path={baseURL} component={ProjectButton} />
      <Route exact path={baseURL} component={Home} />
      <Route exact path={baseURL + '/about'} component={About} />
      <Route exact path={baseURL + '/work'} component={Work} />
      <Route exact path={baseURL + '/projects'} component={Projects} />
    </React.Fragment>
  </Router>
```

Comment: You can handle this in your `ProjectButton` component

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with render props:

```
<Route path={baseURL} render={props =>
  <>
    <Home />
    <ProjectButton />
  </>
} />

<Route {baseURL + '/projects'} render={props =>
  <Projects />
} />
```

You can also pass multiple components for a route, see [this](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3/docs/API.md#named-components)

Or why not handle it in your component? Return null for certain paths *(I personally would prefer this one)*

```
render() {
    const {pathname} = this.props.location;
    if(pathname === "/projects") {
        return null;
    }

    ..
    ..
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I used the second option

Answer (score 1):

```
const matched = useRouteMatch("/projects");  
 return (
<Route path={"/"} render={() => (!matched ? <YourComponent /> : null)} />);
```

With this approach, you can blacklist multiple routes as you can provide an array of routes too in the *useRouterMatch* hook.